# Focus does not advance by pressing the "next" button (delphi)

Tags: android, delphi

I have 4 Tedit in my form, all formated with tab order of 0 at 3 (as shown in the attached image).[image]

But, when i click in the next button in my cellphone, the focus is not changing...

And if I type some text, hit the "next" button (which does nothing) and then manually change the focus from one to the other and continue typing, it copies all of the text from Tedit1 and paste it into Tedit2, as if it had complemented the same Tedit .

I already searched for similar problems but I did not find anyone with this same problem ...

Anyone have any guesses what could be going wrong? I use Delphi Tokyo, and I'm developing for an Android device.

Obs: I already tried check the "KillFocusByReturn" and on function "onExit" of the Tedit1, put on "Tedit2.SetFocus", but this not work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, when i click in the next button in my cellphone, the focus is not changing...

Per the [`ReturnKeyType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Edit.TCustomEdit.ReturnKeyType) documentation:

> Indicates the [type of action](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Types.TReturnKeyType) that the edit control performs when you are editing the text of the control and you press the return key on the virtual keyboard. The run-time platform uses this value to determine the type of return button that it displays on the virtual keyboard for the edit control.
>
> **The value of `ReturnKeyType` does not affect the actual action that the edit control performs when you press the return key. To define that action, use the [`OnKeyUp`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.OnKeyUp) event.**

So, you need to assign an `OnKeyUp` event handler to `Edit1`, and when it indicates the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is pressed, have it call `Edit2.SetFocus()`.  And then do the same thing for `Edit2` for the next control.  And so on as needed.

Comment: This works perfectly, but the another problem mentioned: "if change the focus from one to the other and continue typing, it copies all of the text from Tedit1 and paste it into Tedit2, as if it had complemented the same Tedit." continues.. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Note: Before, this problem only happens if I change it manually. Now it happens even if it is automatically. After a few tests, I realized that if I use the "KillFocusByReturn" function, delphi will not copy the text from edit1 to edit2, but if I keep this function enabled, will not be able to change from one to another.

Comment: @user3602803 [file a bug report with Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Return key to shift the focus to the next control, you might want to try something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = vkReturn then
  begin
    Key := vkTab;
    KeyDown(Key, KeyChar, Shift);
  end;
end;
```